# Почему при пустом текстовом поле выполняется условие?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть метод

```
public void createFile() {
   if (!richTextBox.Text.Length.Equals(null)) {
          DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
           "Сохранить файл?",
            "Сохранение",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
            MessageBoxIcon.Question,
            MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
            MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly
            );
            if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
                this.saveFileAs();
                richTextBox.Clear();
            }
        };
    }
```

Вызываю его по нажатии на кнопку моего текстового редактора. Почему при пустом текстовом поле срабатывает первое условие? Хотя в поле нет текста (и пробелов тоже). Вот скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(richTextBox.Text)` для проверки наличия текста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у пустого поля `Text` равен пустой строке?

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(richTextBox.Text)) {
```

Answer (score 4):

Длина текста пустого поля — 0, а не `null`. Это разные значения, следующий код выведет `False`:

```
 Console.WriteLine(0.Equals(null));
```

`null` обычно используется для обозначения отсутствия чего-то, а не пустого размера.

Корректное сравнение может выглядеть так:

```
if(richTextBox.Text.Length!=0)
```

Но лучше воспользоваться [вариантом @Igor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087808/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5#1087811), он лучше читается.

Answer (score 2):

Даже если у текстового поля или `RichTextEdit` будет, или не будет текста, вы проверяете:

```
richTextBox.Text.Length.Equals(null)
```

Где в свойстве `Length` тип `int` *(не ссылочный)*, а он не может быть равен `null`.

Проверяйте не длину текста, а содержание текста, т.е.:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(...)) { ... }
```

или если вам не нужно и пробелы, то:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(...)) { ... }
```